# When is a constraint needed to be put on a primary and foreign key?

Tags: sql, database

I am new to SQL and am creating a small set of tables. Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Patients_T
          (PatientID            INTEGER(11,0)     NOT NULL,
           PatientName          VARCHAR2(30)      NOT NULL,
           PatientAddress       VARCHAR2(40),     NOT NULL,
           PatientPhone         INTEGER,          NOT NULL,
           CareCenterID         INTEGER(11,0)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Patient_PK PRIMARY KEY(PatientID))
CONSTRAINT Patient_FK FOREIGN KEY(CareCenterID) REFERENCES CareCenter_T(CareCenterID);
```

In reading through examples of creating tables, some tables enforce a constraint on primary and secondary keys as above. I don't fully understand when should the CONSTRAINT be placed on a primary or secondary key? Shouldn't that always be there since you always want a unique primary key?

Comment: You might not want to add a constraint if insert speed is valued over data integrity. You also might not want a constraint if you want duplicates (for counting or whatnot). It's best practice to add them, but by no means written in stone.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint is not an addition to the key, it is defining the key.  When you ask *"when should the CONSTRAINT be placed on a primary or secondary key?"* you're thinking incorrectly about the situation. Without the constraint, you don't *have* a key.

In other words, there is no situation where you can have a key without a constraint. If there is no constraint, there is no key, regardless of what you decide to name the columns.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is filled with confusion.  "Secondary keys" are not "foreign keys".  Here is a fast synopsis.

1. You should always declare primary keys on the table.  The most typical way is:

   ```
   PatientID INTEGER(11) PRIMARY KEY
   ```

   (The `NOT NULL` is optional because it is part of the definition of a primary key.)

   This is the in-line version.  You can also do this on another line in the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

   ```
   PatientID INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
   . . .
   PRIMARY KEY (PatientId)
   ```

   Or using an explicit `CONSTRAINT` statement:

   ```
   PatientID INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
   . . .
   CONSTRAINT pk_patients_patientid PRIMARY KEY (PatientId)
   ```

   All three of these are essentially identical.  Naming the constraint can be useful in some cases.
2. You want to declare foreign keys.  These can also be inline (in most databases):

   ```
   CareCenterID INTEGER(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES CareCenter_T(CareCenterId)
   ```

   The purpose of explicitly declaring a foreign key is so the *database* guarantees that the values are consistent.
3. If another column or set of columns are unique, then you should declare them as unique.

Comment: Thanks this helped!